# Tools to retrieve static content from JSP and JS files - ANTLR?

Tags: javascript, jsp, localization, antlr

I am trying to find out if there are any tools that exist that will get all the static content (for localization) from JSP and JS files. We want to automate the process of finding the static content from JSP and create resource bundles with them.

After some analysis it seems like some form of this can be achieved using ANTLR and XML grammar for ANTLR - http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/1.+Lexer
That is use ANTLR with XML grammar to parse JSP and use StringTemplate to output in to property bundle.

Kindly let me know if somebody has attempted same succesfully.Any help or pointer is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you always end up discovering is that a half-baked solution is half-baked.  Trying to parse JSP or JS (for the latter you really mean HTML with embedded JS?) you need parsers that will handle JSP and HTML.   XML looking like HTML won't cut it; you'll just end up with parsing errors.

So, you can try to bend ANTLR's XML parser and with sufficient effort you might succeed. But then this project turns in to one of bending parsers, rather than doing localization.

Our DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit has full parsers for JSP and for JavaScript embedded in HTML, and for HTML.   These parsers build full ASTs automatically and make their content available for custom output purposes.

Comment: Ok Thanks. I will check same is DMS software toolkit an opensource toolkit.

Comment: DMS is a commercial product.  ANTLR et al are "open source" (a euphemism that many folks use for the word "free").  The difference is your labor, which is not open source.